# ServiceStack CORS request failing even though OPTIONS preflight checks out

Tags: servicestack, cors

I have enabled the CORS feature in ServiceStack, for all verbs, standard headers plus a few custom ones, and all origins. From my Angular application, I am getting the CORS "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when trying to make a PUT call to the server. If I look at my traffic, I see the OPTIONS preflight request to the resource returning with a valid 200 message, and the ACAO header is present and set to *.

```
// CORS PREFLIGHT REQUEST
OPTIONS /referral HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-uatoken, x-ualocation, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

// CORS RESPONSE
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.020 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-UAToken, X-UAUser, X-UALocation, Authorization
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 17:27:47 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Note: I am using angular-file-upload library to make this request as multipart/form-data (pulling files from Request.Files and deserializing data from Request.FormData on the server). Debugging the second request (the actual PUT) in Chrome has that message about "Provisional headers are shown", so I'm not sure how useful that data is:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary3rvpR6k8pz4rghGy
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:9000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
X-UALocation:7
X-UAToken:yoqoByj-T1SBDHCYir92JQ
Request Payload
...etc...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers besides Chrome? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21103081/215502

Comment: I've been trying to work out the same problem myself since yesterday. Only difference is I'm using jQuery File Upload. At first I thought it was possibly the localhost chrome CORS issue. But I've put on test server in IIS and same issues, all browsers. The preflight goes through as expected, the file upload begins. Then when its done posting the file Chrome responds with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Even though I'm using the global CorsFeature plugin in ServiceStack... ALL REQUESTS HAVE THAT HEADER!!!

Comment: One other thing I've also noticed, I can do a simple $.ajax POST to the same endpoint and it will succeed. Also if I were to do a file upload via curl, it proceeds as expected and in the response headers I see all the Access-Control-Allow-* headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the preflight check is requesting a PUT verb? You might want to check into setting up IIS for PUT/DELETE verbs (it's a whole nother can of worms). Or just try the request as a POST to see if that works, then you know it might be just the verb in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this issue in the past, and I can't believe I didn't recognize it until now. It's common in any runtime environment you deal with for file uploads like PHP or Tomcat. The problem isn't your CORS setup at all (since the preflight check is passing). Unless its something entirely else my guess is you ran into the ASP.NET and IIS max request limit! By default these are both very low (4MiB). Very simple to solve, just need to add some stuff to your web.config. The IIS settings are only necessary if you on IIS7.5+ I believe. It may also be recommended to change the executionTimeout depending on how long you are going to allow the upload to run (which will depend on speed of client and size of file).

I finally recognized the issue for what it was when I finally ran the ServiceStack project in debug mode and told it to raise all .NET exceptions to me. Attempted to upload a large enough file (I was testing in curl with really small ones! doh!), and then the exception hit me plain and clear. System.Web.HttpException "Maximum request length exceeded."

Here's example of what you need to do

```
  <system.web>
    <!-- maxRequestLength size is specified in kiB (int32). this controls max length handled by ASP.NET
         set to 2GiB currently

         executionTimeout is seconds before request is shutdown.
         set to 2 hours currently
         -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="7200" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- size is specified in bytes (uint32). this controls max length of IIS
             set to 2GiB currently -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Interesting points about file sizes, and I've made adjustments to my web.config just in case, but this is not my issue. In fact, I get the weird CORS problem even when no file is submitted and I'm just sending the JSON in the multipart form.

Comment: Darn, well I saved you time later hopefully about the filesize issues :). I see the preflight check is requesting a PUT verb? You might also wanna check into setting up IIS for PUT/DELETE verbs (it's a whole nother can of worms). I'd give the request a try just as a POST to see if that works, then you know it might be just the verb in IIS.

Comment: That's a good idea as PUT's are "complex" and POST's are "simple". Not sure why. I wanted to keep things clean where "PUT" = create new item and "POST" = update existing item, but I might try all POST's and see if that helps. I'll update here if it does. Thanks!

Comment: please add your suggestion to switch the PUT verb to POST as an answer and I'll accept it all. day. long. I made the change and everything is super hunky dorey now. I can't believe it. These CORS errors have made dev validation and troubleshooting a PITA, but no more! Thank you for the suggestion.