# Angular JSONP request

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

I'm trying to get a jsonp response from an api call api.brewerydb.com. However, it's not wrapping the json with a function on its call back. Here is my code:

```
app.factory('beer', ['$http',function($http){
  var url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/beers?key=MYKEY&application/json&name=oberon&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

  $http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
      return data;
    });
}]);
```

It is returning json data, however I get a syntax error at a file whose name is the url I passed and it contains the json data.

I discovered that the api does not support jsonp which is why this isn't working out for me

Comment: What do you mean by "I get a syntax error at a file whose name is the url I passed"?

Comment: hey i looked at BreweryDB's api docs and posted a possible solution below. give it a shot -- GL!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your url may be incorrect: '../application/json..' is for an optional `HTTP_ACCEPT` header per their api docs here: [breweryDB](http://www.brewerydb.com/developers/docs) , so remove it from the `var url` string if its not needed.
2. Per their docs, the default return type is `JSON`, so no need to pass an extra parameter if its not needed.
3. Try this instead (for the endpoint `/Beers`) per their [endpoint doc](http://www.brewerydb.com/developers/docs-endpoint/beer_index) :

`var url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/beers?key=MYKEY&name=oberon&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";`

4. Go get them beers!

   ---

   EDIT: code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/r47y3mq3/1/ copy/paste to your local dev environment and use Safari.  
   Using Chrome results in an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header concern as discussed here: [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102690/angularjs-not-detecting-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to change anything. Something I did notice though other apis wrap the json response in a method called JSON_CALLBACK. like this one. https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/orbitalofficial/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=JSON_CALLBACK  The beer api though does not do this. Could this be an issue with their api not accepting callback as a parameter?

Comment: it works in `Safari` using either $http.get(url) or $http.jsonp(urlWithCallback) ..i'll copy/paste the code i tried on my local dev environment....so Chrome (and jsfiddle.net) has some access control issues as documented here: [access-control-allow-origin-header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102690/angularjs-not-detecting-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: added link to jsfiddle in my answer .. GL!

Answer (score 0):

I was having some similar issues. You have `name=oberon` which is a brewery, but you are searching for beers in your url.

If you tried:

```
var url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/breweries?key=MYKEY&application/json&name=oberon&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
```

...you'd get an array of all the beers in the Oberon brewery.