# Binding form-data along with image from HTML page to Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to bind **form-data along with image(s)** from HTML page to **Angular Controller**, then append form-data with image data, and finally POST data to an API.

So I searched, and got to know that, sadly AngularJs doesn't have any directive for image files.
So the ultimate solution I got is to create a custom directive, append form-data with image(s), and then POST that data to server. 

**What I tried:** 

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
<input type="text"  ng-model="UserName" required="required">
<input type="text"  ng-model="FirstName" required="required">
<input type="file"  ng-model="Image" required="required">
<button type="submit" ng-click="product()">save</button>
</form>
```

**Custom Directive :**

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**POST Method :**

```
scope.product = function() {
     var pro = $scope.pro;
     console.log('Form Data : ' + pro);
    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($scope.Image, function(file) {
        fd.append('file', file);
    });
    fd.append('pro', JSON.stringify($scope.product));
    $http.post('/products/createProduct', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': undefined
            }
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.ListProducts = data;
            console.log($scope.ListProducts );
        });

}
```

But the problem is, nothing is binding to the controller, and every-time my object is empty. 
I even tried logging data to console, but got nothing inside data.
I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
Please help..

---

## Update

I am able to bind data, but while posting image-path along with other form-data I am getting all null.

> angular.js:14642 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transfor‌​mRequest":[null],"tr‌​ansformResponse":[nu‌​ll],"jsonpCallbackPa‌​ram":"callback","url‌​":"/products/createP‌​roduct","data":{"pro‌​ductStock":[{"price"‌​:"","color":""}],"pr‌​oductThumbnail":{"0"‌​:{}}},"headers":{"Ac‌​cept":"application/j‌​son, text/plain, /","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"status‌​Text":""} error

Comment: Keep in mind that uploading images with the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is not efficient as the [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) adds a 33% extra overhead. Consider uploading the file directly and using [url parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for additional data.

Comment: @georgeawg: How can I do that?

Comment: Status of -1 usually means a [CORS problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The browser has blocked the XHR because it violates [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734865/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header), Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs), Possible duplicate of [Angular HTTP: Status -1 and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880660/5535245), etc. – georgeawg 5 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type=file>` element does not by default work with the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). It needs a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

### Working Demo of "files-input" Directive that Works with `ng-model`

```js
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>AngularJS Input `type=file` Demo</h1>
    
    <input type="file" files-input ng-model="fileArray" multiple>
    
    <h2>Files</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="file in fileArray">
      {{file.name}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

---

*Thanks for the answer. I tried your code, and getting:*

> angular.js:14642 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transfor‌​mRequest":[null],"tr‌​ansformResponse":[nu‌​ll],"jsonpCallbackPa‌​ram":"callback","url‌​":"/products/createP‌​roduct","data":{"pro‌​ductStock":[{"price"‌​:"","color":""}],"pr‌​oductThumbnail":{"0"‌​:{}}},"headers":{"Ac‌​cept":"application/j‌​son, text/plain, /","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"status‌​Text":""} error

In my experience, the most common cause of status of a `-1`, is that the browser blocked the response because of a violation of [Same Origin Policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. For example, [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) follow the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So, a web application using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) *could only* make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow cross-domain requests.

[image]

The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism gives web servers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers. Modern browsers use CORS in an API container - such as [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) - to mitigate risks of cross-origin HTTP requests.

See [Use CORS to allow cross-origin access.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I tried your code, and getting **angular.js:14642 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/products/createProduct","data":{"productStock":[{"price":"","color":""}],"productThumbnail":{"0":{}}},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}** error

Comment: Oh okay.If I am using `<input type="file" files-input ng-model="product.productThumbnail" multiple>` then only I am getting above error.But if I am using `<input type="file" files-input ng-model="fileArray" multiple>`, then there is no error,but that image name is not getting stored in database.

Comment: I am getting this value in network-tab:`productThumbnail: {name: {0: {}}`,as you can see there is no image name.

Answer (score 0):

I made improve to your code. Basically you was using ng-model, instead of file-model like your directive says, also fd.append File no need iteraction if only have one file. Check the code and the plnkr.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.product = function() {
     var pro = $scope.pro;
     var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('file', $scope.form.Image);
    fd.append('pro', JSON.stringify($scope.form));
    $http.post('/products/createProduct', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': undefined
            }
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.ListProducts = data;
            console.log($scope.ListProducts );
        });
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
    <input type="text"  ng-model="form.UserName" required="required">
    <input type="text"  ng-model="form.FirstName" required="required">
    <input type="file" file-model="form.Image" required="required">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="product()">save</button>
</form>

{{form.Image.name}}
```

[PLNKR EXAMPLE](https://embed.plnkr.co/L4euOOYAVZjhuPoiRZAb/)

**UPDATE **

in the network could see this. when sending data.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am able to bind data, but while posting image-path along with other form-data I am getting all null.

Comment: in network tab on developers console in browser you can check if data is sending to the api, and how is the data names.

Comment: the formdata sendint has to parts one name file an other pro

Comment: if api is PHP  $_FILE('file');

Comment: Just now I checked in network-tab , i am getting null.

Comment: I have nodeJs REStful API

Comment: im put  a pickture consuming the plnkr i made. and it has body data.

Comment: so in the nodejs api you need to catch the formdata file, and formdata, pro.

Comment: How to catch from-data in nodeJS?

Comment: thats is off-topic to your original question lol... but, i think this could help `app.post('/products/createProduct',function(request,response){ console.log(request.body) //you will get your data in this as object. })`

Comment: try request.file instead body.

Comment: Did that, still got nothing

Comment: It's not that nothing is getting posted to dB, only fields with default value are posted to Db, not the ones I am filling in the form.

Comment: sorry dude, i think now the issues are for API, if you confirm that the formdata is sending try find out how in node can catch, all a mention above found here in the platform.

Comment: It's not that nothing is getting posted to dB, only fields with default value are posted to Db, not the ones I am filling in the form.

Comment: If I post data without image field,I mean after removing that field from the form,then entire form data is getting posted to the DataBase.

Comment: again i think is more issues from api on how to obtain the form-data

Comment: sorry cant help i have not skills on nodejs

Comment: Hi,one more doubt, why Image object is showing as null in the network tab?