# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when calling REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Script:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('https://172.29.7.37:8443/SpringRestPRD/rest/l1values').success(function(response) {
        $scope.abc = response.L1Values;
    });

});
```

Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in abc">
    <td> {{a.Registration}}</td>
    <td> {{a.Cancellation Due to Default}}</td>
    <td> {{a.Transfers}}</td>
</tr>
```

Nothing is showing up in my JSP page and I am getting this error:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://172.29.7.37:8443/SpringRestPRD/rest/l1values. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Try - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102690/angularjs-not-detecting-access-control-allow-origin-header.
And edit your question so the snippet will work.

Comment: how i overcome this problem please help...